# Empty set clarification

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Is $∅ ∈ \{\{∅\}\}$ true or false?
I think it is false and my reasoning is this,

> ∅ is an element of a set of subset ∅

Since ∅ is an element of the set, it is therefore not an element of the *subset inside the set*. Am I right?

Is ∅ ⊄ {∅,1,2} true or false?
I think it is true and my reasoning is this,

> ∅ is not a subset of set ∅, 1, 2

∅ is an empty set therefore it is a subset of {∅, 1, 2}

Lastly, is it right to say that in *any* power set of X, ∅ will always either be ∈ or ⊆ of power set X?

Comment: The *empty* set is a subset of **every** set.

Comment: And yes, for **every** set $X$, bot $X$ and $\emptyset$ are subsets of $X$ and thus elements of its power-set.

Comment: Sorry I am still extremely confused. So is the way I derive my statement correct?

Comment: To say that the *empty* set is a subset of **every** set implies that $\emptyset \subseteq \{ \emptyset, 1, 2 \}$ as well as $\emptyset \subseteq \{  1, 2 \}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The emptyset, which we'll denote $\varnothing$, is a subset of every set, and it is even a subset of the empty set itself.

$\varnothing \subset \{\{\varnothing\}\}$ but $\varnothing \notin \{\{\varnothing\}\}$.  Our set has one single element, $\{\varnothing\}$, the set containing the emptyset, so $\varnothing$ is not an element of the initial set.

However $\{\varnothing\} \in \{\{\varnothing\}\}$.

And $\{\{\varnothing\}\} \subseteq \{\{\varnothing\}\}$.

---

In your second example, let's call $S= \{\varnothing, 1, 2\}$.

Then $\varnothing \subseteq S$, because the emptyset is a subset of every set.   $\varnothing \in S$, as well, as it is an element of S. And $\{\varnothing\} \subseteq S$, just like $\{1, 2\} \subseteq S$.

So the powerset of S, the set containing all subsets of S is as follows:

$$\{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}, \{\varnothing, 1,\}, \{\varnothing, 2\}, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1, 2\}, \{\varnothing, 1, 2\}\}$$

Comment: For the second explanation, is it suppose to be ⊆ instead of ⊂? I am trying to make sense of your explanation at the moment. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, we'll use that notation, except in the second example, all subsets I mention are proper subsets so $\subset$ is okay.  But it never hurts to use subseteq:  For example, in the second case, all the subsets of S include $\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}, \{\varnothing, 1,\}, \{\varnothing, 2\}, \{1\}, \{2,\}, \{1, 2\}, \{\varnothing 1, 2\}$$

Comment: Thank you. So it is right to say that the empty set is a subset of the power set X whether it is "an element of" or "a subset of"?

Comment: Yes for any set $X$, the $\cal P(X)$ contains all subsets of $X$ (including the emptyset subset X), but also, the empty is then  a subset of $\cal P(X)$.

Comment: I hope I've helped., Sunny.

Comment: I have choices to denote this void set in latex

Comment: @mrs yes.  The empty set can be denoted `\{ \}`: $\{ \}$; `\varnothing`: $\varnothing$; or `\emptyset`: $\emptyset$.

Answer (score 2):

> Is ∅ ∈ {{∅}} true or false?
>   I think it is false and my reasoning is this,
>
> ∅ is an element of a set of subset ∅
>
> Since ∅ is an element of the set, it is therefore not an element of the *subset inside the set*. Am I right?

You put that a little awkwardly, but as I understand it, your reasoning is: "I see that $\emptyset$ is an element of $\{ \emptyset \}$, but that $\{ \emptyset \}$ is itself an element of the whole set $\{ \{ \emptyset \} \}$ (as you put it: the $\{ \emptyset \}$ is 'inside' the $\{ \{ \emptyset \} \}$), and it is therefore not an element of that 'larger' set $\{ \{ \emptyset \} \}$.

OK, that doesn't follow. Just because $X \in Y$ and $Y \in Z$ does not mean that $X \not \in Z$. For example, think of the set $\{ \{ \emptyset \}, \emptyset \}$.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I agree with your last statement but in this case, will it be true or false then?

Comment: @SunnyBoiz In your case you are right that $\emptyset \in \{ \{ \emptyset \} \}$ is false ... it was just that your reasoning left something to be desired ...

Answer (score 1):

***Your conclusion is correct, but the reason you give is wrong.***

Your reason is : since $\emptyset$ it is a subset ( a member of the power set) of the set under consideration,  it is not an element. But consider this counter example, where 0 is the number zero : $\{ 0 , \{0\}\}$ . The set $\{0\}$ is a subset , but *also* an element.

---

- The reason you could have given is : ***the fact that $\emptyset$ is an element of an element of the set under consideration does not imply that it is also an element of the set under consideration;*** witness, the empty set can be seen nowhere " on the list" of the elements of the set under consideration.
- Determining whether something is an element of a set is as simple as this : ***make a list of all the elements; if you cannot find the object on the list, it means it is not an element of the set.***

The list of the elements of $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ is very short.

It looks as this. List : $\{\emptyset\}$.

So 1 and only 1 element, which is a singleton set.

Do you see $\emptyset$ on this list? No, on the list you see a set that has one element, but the empty set has no element.

[image]